# Set new column value based on TRUE/FALSE derived from existing columns

Tags: r, data.table

I want to create a new column in a `data.table` object, and the values should be set based on matching a number in a range. The `from` and `to` of the range are two columns in existing `data.table` object.

**[Data]**

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(from=sample(10000))[, to:=from+sample(10000)]

> head(DT)
from    to
1: 2656  3304
2: 3721 10487
3: 5728 13081
4: 9080 10193
5: 2017  2484
6: 8980 10289
```

**[My Approach]**

In this case, I want to add a new `boolean` column `flag`, which returns `TRUE` if 6500 is in the range of `[from, to]`.

This is my attempt:

```
DT[, flag:=0][DT[, .I[6500 %in% seq(from, to, by=1)], by=1:nrow(DT)][[1]], flag:=1]

> table(DT$flag)

   0    1 
5567 4433
```

**[Question]**

The code took some time to run, and as you can imagine, it will take more time if `n` in `sample(n)` gets bigger.

My question is: **Is there a better way to do this?** Better in terms of speed and code readability (I believe my code is not intuitive at all).

Comment: Try `help("%between%")` and `help("%chin%")`

Comment: If you want to ask a question about characters, you should do so (as a new question)... all the answers below seem to handle your example just fine. Moreover, they will extent to characters because inequalities work just fine between characters, like `"6500" <= "65"`

Comment: @Frank, I updated my post. Sorry for not being thoughtful when posting.

Comment: @Frank, I gave some thoughts and do not think I should create a new question, because my title suggests subsetting `data.table` based on `TRUE`/`FALSE` for each row. That's why I used `.I(...)` in my solution. My initial example was misleading, so I changed to a more relevant one. Let me know if you disagree.

Comment: that's a completly different question ......

Comment: Yes, I disagree. The reason I suggested asking a new question is because it is inconsiderate to the folks who have answered your original question, below (and makes their answers look wrong). I don't think the title has bearing on whether to ask a new question or not.

Comment: @Frank Make sense. I will ask a new question.

Comment: In case anyone wants to follow through, the new question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842356/r-data-table-set-new-column-with-logical-value-if-a-weekday-is-between-a-date-ra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use:

```
DT[, flag := +(from < 6500 & to > 6500)]
```

The statement between the `()` gives the conditions, the `+` makes it a logical integer (either a `0` or a `1`). This gives the same result as:

```
DT[, flag := ifelse(from < 6500 & to > 6500, 1, 0)]
```

Another possibility (suggested by @Frank):

```
DT[, flag := mapply(between,6500,from,to)]
```

However the `mapply` call leads to quite some overhead. Just using:

```
DT[, flag := between(6500,from,to)]
```

is a lot faster as can be seen in the following speed comparison between the different approaches:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(q = DT[, flag:=0][DT[, .I[6500 %in% seq(from, to, by=1)], by=1:nrow(DT)][[1]], flag:=1],
               j1 = DT[, flag := +(from < 6500 & to > 6500)],
               j2 = DT[, flag := ifelse(from < 6500 & to > 6500, 1, 0)],
               j3 = DT[, flag := mapply(between,6500,from,to)],
               j4 = DT[, flag := between(6500,from,to)],
               nikos = DT[, flag:=0][from<=6500 & to>=6500, flag:=1],
               jimbo = DT[, flag := 6500<=to & 6500>=from])

Unit: microseconds
  expr         min           lq         mean       median           uq         max
     q 2424842.405 2498646.2495 2638230.4775 2545083.2020 2684601.6290 4336768.458
    j1     843.639     896.2505    1074.3921     955.3120    1047.0570    3689.399
    j2    2063.674    2205.7850    2766.0470    2282.0050    3115.9475    7978.479
    j3   16072.188   16406.6920   19550.4140   19056.4665   20915.1620   75465.362
    j4     687.094     731.7385     877.6009     780.1280     858.3825    3073.322
 nikos    1077.945    1186.2395    1424.4156    1290.7015    1389.8500    3699.621
 jimbo     759.372     836.2075    1000.6322     884.4715     958.0035    3016.492
```

So, the fastest approach (the `between` option in `j4`) is about 3000 times faster than the original approach in the question.

Comment: `ifelse` is much slower though

Comment: @DavidArenburg it's just to illustrate what the first statement does

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: I'd say I am good enough :) Thanks for posting the timings. Very interesting indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, why don't you do something like this:

```
DT[,flag:=0]
DT[from<=6500 & to>=6500,flag:=1]
```

This should have the same result unless I didn't understand your question.

Comment: You could also simplify this to `DT[, flag:=0][from<=6500 & to>=6500, flag:=1]`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(from=sample(10000))[, to:=from+sample(10000)]
DT[, flag := 6500<=to & 6500>=from]

> table(DT$flag)

FALSE  TRUE 
 5567  4433
```